# Jekyll Image Updating - Github Chart

Tags: html, css, image, sass, jekyll

Hello I am using the https://ghchart.rshah.org/ API to embed an image of my github chart into my jekyll website. However, the image won't update daily even though the src link I include does. Here is my HTML and CSS
**HTML:**

My Activity

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper
    max-width: 960px
    +display(flex)
    margin: 0 auto
    +align-items(center)
    +justify-content(space-around)
    padding-bottom: 75px

img
 @media screen and (max-width:860px)
    max-width: 100%
```

Comment: Please post your code/text by copy paste and now with images

Comment: Incredibly sorry but I do not have enough points attached to my account to post images without a link....

Comment: You have enough points to copy/paste the code as text though :)

Comment: whoops just did it tyyy!